# AWS API Gateway - "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I aim to create a custom domain for private API Gateway endpoints in VPC. To achieve this, I created an AWS Private CA and requested the private certificate for the domain *.test.aws. Then created an AWS Load Balancer with a listener in HTTPS (port 443) with an already-created private certificate. The Target Group points to the IP addresses for "execute-api" endpoints inside the VPC. The next step was to create a private Hosted Zone in Route 53, with a new A record "api.test.aws" that redirects to the ALB domain name. Finally, set up a custom domain name with "api.test.aws" using the certificate for my API Gateway resource.

After all of these steps, whenever call the "https://api.test.aws", I get an error "self signed certificate in certificate chain" The request never reaches the target lambda function. For instance, tested the "https://api.test.aws" which reaches the lambda (updated ALB of port 80)

Any idea what may cause the following error?

Comment: Well, that would be a self signed certificate in the certificate chain… One self-signed certificate could have been created by anyone. I can very easily create a self signed certificate for www.amazon.com for example.